# How to store the Datagridview cells value in to 2D array

Tags: arrays, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewrow

I am developing a program in VB.net using datagridview. My datagridview column number is fixed. The number of rows will vary. After adding each row, I want to store the cell values in an array. How do I write code?
 
Or else, after adding all rows (say, 7 rows, for example), I want to store or create an array from the datagridview cells.

Thanks in advance.
R.Srinivasan

Sample Coding for creating an 2D array from datagridview cells. Vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim myArray=myDataGridView.Rows(myDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex).DataBoundItem.row 'Is Array row
```

Comment: The DataSource of your DataGridView is connected to the DataTable Object?

Comment: Thanks Mr.Mansour. I am filling the datagridview using textbox

Comment: Hi. If you used the DataTable to fill the dataGridView, you would get a better result.Because the DataTable can be an array.

Comment: Oh! But how to create data table? Since I am new to VB i m not aware of data table. Can you explain with small example.

Comment: If you want to use a database, you must ensure the existence of database engines. A. If the Microsoft Access software is installed, the OLEDB engine will be installed with it. How many versions of Microsoft Access do you have installed?

Comment: I am using vb2010